# Pandas dataframe values reassignment by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have rand_df1:

```
np.random.seed(1)
rand_df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 40, size=(3, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
print(rand_df1, '\n')
```

```
    A   B
0  37  12
1   8   9
2  11   5
```

Also, rand_df2:

```
rand_df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 40, size=(3, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
rand_df2 = rand_df2.loc[rand_df2.index.repeat(rand_df2['B'])]
print(rand_df2, '\n')
```

```
    A  B
1  16  1
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
```

I need to reassign values in the first dataframe col `'A'` with values in `'A'` of the second dataframe by index. Desired output of `rand_df1`:

```
    A  B
0  37  12
1  16  1
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
```

Comment: `rand_df2.combine_first(rand_df1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Henry Yik for his solution:

```
rand_df2.combine_first(rand_df1)
```

```
    A  B
0  37  12
1  16  1
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
2  12  7
```

Also, tested this with extra column in one dataframe, that doesn't appears in second dataframe and backward situation. It works good.

Answer (score 0):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, you are looking to append new rows onto `rand_df2`. These rows are to be selected from `rand_df1` where they have an index which does not appear in `rand_df2`. Is that correct?

This will do the trick:

```
rand_df2_new = rand_df2.append(rand_df1[~rand_df1.index.isin(rand_df2.index)]).sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Tested it with an additional column in ```rand_df1```, that doesn't appears in ```rand_df2```. Values from extra col3 filling with NaN.